# What happens if I publish an iOS by signing it with developer, not distribution certificate?

Tags: ios, xcode

In the build settings of an xcode project for a target, I accidentally configured the iPhone developer code signing indentity for release.
I published the app and it got through the app review process.
Unless xcode does not explicitly override the signing certificate while archiving and submitting to app store, I think the published app is signed using developer certificate.

Am I insinuating right? If yes, what are it's implications? Will push notifications in such an app stop working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unless xcode does not explicitly override the signing certificate while archiving and submitting to app store, I think the published app is signed using developer certificate

It does explicitly override it. During the submission process, as the app is extracted from the archive and uploaded to the app store, a distribution profile is added to the app. You would not have been able to upload the app to the app store if you didn't have the right profile and entitlements.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the prompt reply. That clears it. If I may ask, what is the use of code signing identity under Code Signing (Build Settings) ? I can see that I need to set it to iOS developer to validate the app for publishing. And how it is different from the provisioning profile option under code signing?

Comment: You should not touch the Code Signing build setting. Whether you use automatic signing or not, everything you need to do is configured on the Target's General editing pane.